# In Debian, which package is responsible for creation of /etc/default/grub?

Tags: debian, package-management, grub2, configuration, dpkg

There are many packages which have grub in their names and part of the GRUB (the Grand Unified Boot Loader). The ones which are installed on my system are -

1. grub-common
2. grub-emu
3. grub-pc
4. grub-pc-bin
5. grub-theme-starfield
6. grub2
7. grub2-common
8. grub2-splashimages

I first looked at it to see whether it is a symlinked file or a regular file -

```
 [$] ll -h /etc/default/grub

    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2K 2017-01-22 14:16 /etc/default/grub
```

I had a look but couldn't find anything which would tell me where this file comes from ?

```
[$] dpkg -S /etc/default/grub

dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/default/grub
```

OR

```
[$] dpkg-query -W /etc/default/grub

dpkg-query: no packages found matching /etc/default/grub
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In such cases you can find the relevant package by looking through the post-installation scripts:

```
grep /etc/default/grub /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst
```

This reveals that the file is created by `grub-pc`.